# WordPress User role → Fetch and Print(echo)

Tags: author

1. Subscriber
2. Administrator
3. Editor
4. Author
5. Contributor

Above are the 3 types of users roles defined in the WordPress. Just like we pull authors description:

```
<p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p>
```

How can we pull user role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720949/get-user-role-by-id-wordpress

**Here is their answer:**

You can't get user role directly. First, you have to get the user_meta_data, and it will return an Object that will contain user roles.

**Code:**

```
$user_meta=get_userdata($user_id);

$user_roles=$user_meta->roles; //array of roles the user is part of.
```